# I got a message "no metrics known for pod" when I deploy kubernetes-metric-server

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed metric-server.
but my "kubectl logs metric-server-pod" gave me this message.

```
I0813 02:06:46.985836 1 serving.go:312] Generated self-signed cert (apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.crt, apiserver.local.config/certificates/apiserver.key) I0813
02:06:47.348587 1 secure_serving.go:116] Serving securely on [::]:443 E0813 
02:07:00.339450 1 reststorage.go:128] unable to fetch node metrics for node "client-master": no metrics known for node
```

my kubernetes version :

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{
  Major:"1", Minor:"15", 
  GitVersion:"v1.15.0", 
  GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", 
  GitTreeState:"clean", 
  BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:37:41Z",
  GoVersion:"go1.12.5", 
  Compiler:"gc", 
  Platform:"linux/amd64"
}
```

sure, I added below options on my metric-server-deployment.yaml

```
command: 
- /metrics-server 
- --kubelet-insecure-tls 
- --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,Hostname,InternalDNS,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP
```

I use internal network and I installed kubernetes offline
please, help me..

Comment: Can the hostname `client-master` be resolved in pod? If not, try add `spec. hostAliases` to your pod.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As your advice, I added `spec. hostAliases` but got same message.. sure, I added hostname in /etc/hosts. Is there another way you know?

Comment: After you have added the node's hostname on /etc/hosts file, please run this below command to verify it.                                                       kubectl exec -it metrics-server-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx -n kube-system -- /bin/sh

Comment: @SubramanianManickam I resolved this problem. I used "--v=4" log level option on my metric-server-deployment.yaml and it was just problem which initially occur.